# What to change to optimize mysql system variables on windows?

Tags: mysql

Looking for general pointers to optimize my current settings to get faster query time.
I am already working on explaining my queries and working out indexing, I am just looking for advice on system variables for Windows Vista.

Here are all the current settings that are not 0, NULL, Off or Blank:

```
Bytes_received  286
Bytes_sent  554
Com_change_db   3
Com_select  2
Com_set_option  2
Com_show_status 1
Com_show_variables  1
Connections 6
Created_tmp_files   5
Created_tmp_tables  1
Flush_commands  1
Handler_read_rnd_next   2
Handler_write   1
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   3007
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    5727
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   1
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  3008
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   3
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_seq   37
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    1492657307
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    458
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   1311924
Innodb_data_fsyncs  235
Innodb_data_read    47353856
Innodb_data_reads   2767
Innodb_data_writes  6086
Innodb_data_written 278121984
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  5727
Innodb_dblwr_writes 64
Innodb_log_waits    16
Innodb_log_write_requests   184879
Innodb_log_writes   204
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    100
Innodb_os_log_written   90435072
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    3214
Innodb_pages_read   2757
Innodb_pages_written    5727
Innodb_rows_deleted 171880
Innodb_rows_inserted    208237
Innodb_rows_read    1481968453
Key_blocks_unused   918217
Max_used_connections    4
Open_table_definitions  31
Open_tables 2
Opened_files    194
Queries 97
Questions   9
Select_scan 1
Table_locks_immediate   32
Threads_connected   4
Threads_created 4
Threads_running 2
Uptime  8773
Uptime_since_flush_status   8773
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can install [`perl`](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) in your server i suggest running [`mysqltuner.pl`](http://mysqltuner.com/).

If you can install [`sh`](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) in your server i suggest ruinng [`tuning-primer.sh`](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/).

Both scripts give good suggestions and information about Mysql usage and tunning.